# JavaScript loop does not calculate / show result properly

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$('#customer_info #next_step').click(function() {

    $.getJSON("order/summary_process2.php?jsoncallback=?", function (data) {

        //loop through all items in the JSON array
        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

            //create a container for each comment
            var div = $("<tr>").addClass("row").appendTo("#row");

            //add author name and comment to container
            $("<td>").addClass("space").text(data[x].item_name).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("space").text(data[x].price).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("space").text(data[x].qty).appendTo(div);
            $("<td>").addClass("space").text(data[x].tot_price).appendTo(div);
            //$("<div>").addClass("comment").text(data[x].comment).appendTo(div);

        }

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var total = 0;
            total = data[i].tot_price + total;
        }
        $("#total").html(total);

    });
});
//});
});
```

I'm using `JSON`, but I want to add the total price.

Unfortunately, the result is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Take `var total = 0` out of the loop. You're resetting it on every iteration.

Comment: please explain .. bcoz if i defined out of loop answer is not geting proper

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the variable `total` is limited to the `for` loop, thus it will be `undefined` outside of this scope. Initialize it *before* the loop instead:

```
var total = 0;
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  total = parseInt(data[i].tot_price, 10) + total;
}
```

Also, and based on your comment, I'm assuming you are dealing with strings, so you need to use `parseInt` to parse them before adding to the total.

Comment: @user1668178: You are probably dealing with strings instead of integers. Use `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your total variable out of for loop scope., In for loop scope, it is always reassigning total to 0 in every iteration.

Change this

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   var total = 0;
   total = data[i].tot_price + total;
}
$("#total").html(total);
```

to

```
var total = 0;
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    total += Number(data[i].tot_price);
}
$("#total").html(total);
```

Comment: not working  answer shown is 0150325170 ... actualy i want this 0150+325+170

Comment: ok then cast your values to number like `total += Number(data[i].tot_price);`

Comment: @user1668178, It is getting tot_price as text so convert it to number before adding to total variable.